# Test passes in Test Explorer, fails in NUnit GUI

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, unsafe

I have a special test written in NUnit which passes in Visual Studio Test Explorer but does not pass when it is ran in the NUnit gui. The unit test uses an *Interceptor* class which swaps two methods so that I can use the second method as a fake for the first which is used in the unit under test. This is done with the C# unsafe (unmanaged) code:

```
  public static void Inject( MethodInfo replacedMethod, MethodInfo injectionMethod )
  {
     RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod( replacedMethod.MethodHandle );
     RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod( injectionMethod.MethodHandle );

     unsafe {
        if( IntPtr.Size == 4 ) {

           int* inj = (int*) replacedMethod.MethodHandle.Value.ToPointer() + 2;
           int* tar = (int*) injectionMethod.MethodHandle.Value.ToPointer() + 2;

           if( System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached ) {
              //Version x86 Debug
              byte* injInst = (byte*) *inj;
              byte* tarInst = (byte*) *tar;

              int* injSrc = (int*) (injInst + 1);
              int* tarSrc = (int*) (tarInst + 1);

              Replaced = (((int) tarInst + 5) + *tarSrc) - ((int) injInst + 5);

              *tarSrc = (((int) injInst + 5) + *injSrc) - ((int) tarInst + 5);
              *injSrc = Replaced;
           }
           else {
              //Version x86 Release
              Replaced = *tar;
              *tar = *inj;
              *inj = Replaced;
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

I call the Inject method from my unit test:

```
  public static void SecondMethod( double[] e, out double var1, out double var2, out double var3 )
  { 
     var1 = new Double();
     var2= new Double();
     var3 = new Double();
     var1 = 0.0;
     var2 = 0.0;
     var3 = 0.0;
  }

  [Test]
  public void Utilites_Tanks_ApproximateApogee_ReturnsTrue(){
     double val = 10;
     double[] ecr = { 1.2, 3.4, 5.6, 4.5, 6.7, 8.9 };
     MethodInfo x = typeof( FirstMethodClass ).GetMethods().Single(m => m.Name == "FirstMethod" && m.GetParameters().Length == 4);
     MethodInfo z = typeof( TestClass ).GetMethod( "SecondMethod" );
     Interceptor.Inject( x,z );
     bool stageValue = UnitUnderTestMethodClass.Method( ecr, val, out double[] apogeeInfo2 );
     Assert.That( stageValue, Is.True );
  }
```

This test works as planned; it passed in the Visual Studio test explorer and it does show up in the NUnit gui. The hang up is that it doesn't pass when ran in the NUnit gui. I have run the test in NUnit gui versions 2.6.# and 3.# with the same result. There is another test that I have written that does close to the same thing and it passes. That test is swapping methods with no arguments to pass so the GetMethod portion is done within the Interceptor unlike this test.

I was wondering if the NUnit gui does not play well with unsafe (unmanaged) code. I am referencing the correct build in the NUnit gui as well so I do not believe that this is the issue.

Thanx

Comment: What version of NUnit are you using? The NUnit 3 GUI is currently alpha and the NUnit 2 GUI won't run NUnit 3 tests correctly. What results do you get when you run from the NUnit Console?

Comment: I've installed NUnit 3.9.0 in VS 2017. I have both the NUnit 2.6.3 GUI and the NUnit 3 GUI. In both of these it detects and runs all of the tests without issue. I also get the same result in both GUIs. The assert comes back false when it should be true.  I have debugged the tests as well, and the proper result does come back in Visual Studio.

Comment: @RobProuse That's actually pre-alpha. :-)

Comment: The NUnit 2.x GUI may appear to run NUnit tests, but it runs them as if they were NUnit 2 tests, so you will get unreliable behavior. And as @Charlie says, the NUnit 3 GUI is pre-alpha and hasn't been officially released. I would recommend that you use Visual Studio or the command line runners.